# Add meta tags in GTM (JavaScript code) for Search Console Verification

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to try to pass verification in a non-standard way. Add meta tags `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="G3zZVDOhDEIQRfF2ndWT7icRgZn7YZtEORo1fAbsnY4" />` how JavaScript code in GTM (Custom HTML Tag):

```
<script>
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('name', 'google-site-verification');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'G3zZVDOhDEIQRfF2ndWT7icRgZn7YZtEORo1fAbsnY4');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```

But for some reason, in this way, it does not create a meta tag, and Search Console does not allow verification. You can’t do this? And Yandex.Webmaster too

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the GTM snippet method to verify instead: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en&visit_id=637051133309494101-3963396650&rd=1#verification_details

If you installed GTM correctly as per spec, you shouldn't need to do anything or add any tags.

Comment: I know, can confirm that. I need to understand if JavaScript is allowed to do this. Until it comes out

Comment: For non-standard way by adding a meta tag in JavaScript

Comment: You can't verify the site through JavaScript injection.